# Strip values from HTML with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Trying to strip from

```
<h3 class="s-item__title s-item__title--has-tags" role="text"><div><div class="s-item__title-tag">Nov 14, 2018</div></div>Text I Want</h3>
```

I want the values:
Nov 14, 2018,
Text I Want

I've tried but cannot get to that second value.

Comment: post your python code as well please so we can help you

Answer (score 3):

I used the [strings generator](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) to grab all strings in the html, and store in a list:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<h3 class="s-item__title s-item__title--has-tags" role="text"><div><div class="s-item__title-tag">Nov 14, 2018</div></div>Text I Want</h3>)"""

bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
text = [s for s in bs.h3.strings]

text

['Nov 14, 2018', 'Text I Want']
```

Comment: That's nice, I like this method! You can also throw in some list comp for good measure: `text = [s for s in bs.h3.strings]`

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot : ) And completely agree with you on list comp -- just updated my answer to include it! Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure @ToddS, and glad you found it useful -- if you feel it fully solves your problem, would you mind marking it as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)? Thanks!